# Dispatching from an Azure Pipeline 1 in Repository 1 to Azure Pipeline 2 in Repository 2

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a scenario that I my 'Azure Pipeline 1' in Repository 1 realising a Gradle build, triggered by a push to a branch, after a successful Gradle build should Trigger 'Azure Pipeline 2' in Repository 2, while passing some parameters to the Pipeline 2.

Azure Pipeline 2, should run in the context of Repository 2, so it can't be template that would be included to the Pipeline 1 and run in the context of Repository 1.

I can do something similar with Github Action like this [Workflow Dispatch](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/workflow-dispatch-and-wait) but I can not figure out corresponding way in Azure Pipelines.

So far I found

- an [Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline) but it is 4 years old and seems to be not valid anymore (additionally I can't see anyway to pass parameters)
- Pipeline Resource Repository Triggers

  ```
      resources:
        repositories:
        - repository:
          type: github
          name: xxxxx/repository1
          endpoint: repository1
          trigger:
            branches:
              include:
                - master
  ```

  but this seems does not have any means to pass parameters.

  - multiple checkouts to Repository 1 (so the contents of the Repository 2 is also checked-out to Repository 1)

    ```
        resources:
          repositories:
          - repository: repository2
            type: github
            endpoints: repository2
            name: xxxx/repository
            ref: master

        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - checkout: repository2
    ```

    but I can figure out how to configure Gradle Task to build once for checkout at 'self' and once for 'repository', it seems Gradle has Input Paramters 'workingDirectory' and checkout directory is [predictable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path) but I can figure how to configure [GitVersion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion) to run to different checkout directories other then opening powershell executing GitVersion manually.

    ```
        - task: Gradle@3
          name: selfGradleBuild
          inputs:
            workingDirectory: 'C:\agent\_work\1\s\self'
            gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
            gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
            javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
            jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
            jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
            publishJUnitResults: true
            testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
            tasks: 'build -Pversion=$(version) --no-daemon'

        - task: Gradle@3
          name: repository2GradleBuild
          inputs:
            workingDirectory: 'C:\agent\_work\1\s\repository2'
            gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
            gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
            javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
            jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
            jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
            publishJUnitResults: true
            testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
            tasks: 'build -Pversion=$(version) --no-daemon
    ```

    - or I can write lots of scripts in in powershell to call the REST API to trigger the workflow in repository2

      ```
        - pwsh: |
          $url = 'https://dev.azure.com/MYOrg/MYProject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0'
          $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String] [String]]"
          $headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
          $headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $(SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)")
          $body = "{
             "definition": {
                 "id": "987"
             },
             "templateParameters": {
                "sourceRepo": "repository1",
                "brancheName": "branchA"
             }
          }"
          $response = Invoke-RestMethod $url - Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
          $response | ConvertTo-Json
      ```

  but this way is no where elegant as [Github Actions Dispatch](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/workflow-dispatch-and-wait) version

Which method would you choose? Or better how would you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well at the end of the day, I decide to use REST API Version, if you like to see how it is done, here is link for my blog about [Azure DevOps Pipelines for CI / CD](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/02/26/azure-devops-pipelines-for-an-ideal-ci-cd-for-your-kubertnetes-deployments/#dispatch-mechanism/)